Junit Mockito Testcase for Rest API controller class taking boolean as path parameter
I am new to Junit Mockito testcase. I am trying to write REST API controller class .But facing some issue.Can someone please help me on writing the test case.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storage-connector")
public class BigQueryController {

    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BigQueryController.class);

    @Autowired
    private BigQueryService bigQueryService;
    
    boolean isSchedulerStarted = false;
    //boolean isSchedulerStarted = true;
    
    @PostMapping("/postBigqueryData")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageDTO> postDatatoBigquery(@RequestParam("schedular") boolean schedular) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    
    
    
      /*  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                {new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
                };
    
    
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(CommonConstants.SSL);
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());*/
        MessageDTO result=new MessageDTO();
        if (schedular) {
            isSchedulerStarted = true;
            result=postDatatoBigqueryScheduled();
            if(result.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
            }else{
                return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
            }
    
        } else if (!schedular && isSchedulerStarted) {
            isSchedulerStarted = false;
            result=postDatatoBigqueryScheduled();
            handleSchedulerTime();
            result.setMessage(CommonConstants.SCHEDULAR_STOPPED);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }
    
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    
    }

Also one more test case on
your t@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storage-connector")
public class BigQueryController {

    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BigQueryController.class);

    @Autowired
    private BigQueryService bigQueryService;
    
    boolean isSchedulerStarted = false;
    //boolean isSchedulerStarted = true;

    @PostMapping("/postBigqueryData")
    public ResponseEntity<MessageDTO> postDatatoBigquery(@RequestParam("schedular") boolean schedular) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {



      /*  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]
                {new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
                };


        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(CommonConstants.SSL);
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());*/
        MessageDTO result=new MessageDTO();
        if (schedular) {
            isSchedulerStarted = true;
            result=postDatatoBigqueryScheduled();
            if(result.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
            }else{
                return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
            }

        } else if (!schedular && isSchedulerStarted) {
            isSchedulerStarted = false;
            result=postDatatoBigqueryScheduled();
            handleSchedulerTime();
            result.setMessage(CommonConstants.SCHEDULAR_STOPPED);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);

    }

your text
I have written like
@Test
    public void testPostDatatoBigquery() throws Exception {
        boolean schedular = true;

        MessageDTO messageDTOProxy = new MessageDTO();
        messageDTOProxy.setJobId("e101");
        messageDTOProxy.setMessage("Success");

        when(bigQueryService.postDatatoBigquery()).thenReturn(messageDTOProxy);

        //  when(bigQueryService.postDatatoBigquery().thenReturn(ArgumentMatchers.anyObject());

        ResponseEntity<MessageDTO> messageDTO = bigQueryController.postDatatoBigquery(schedular);
        assertNotNull(messageDTO);

        ///MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/postBigqueryData").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

        // assertThat(messageDTO.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(201);
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        String scheduler1=mapper.writeValueAsString(schedular);

        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder=MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/postBigqueryData").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(scheduler1);

        ResultActions perform=this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder);
          MvcResult andReturn= perform.andReturn();
          MockHttpServletResponse response= andReturn.getResponse();
         int status= response.getStatus();
         assertEquals(201,status);
    }

`But getting NullPointerException due to getting null in requestBuilder.

  MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder=MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/postBigqueryData").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(scheduler1);


Where do you assign bigQueryService? How do you assign the field in your controller (and why are you using the discouraged field injection and not the recommended constructor injection)? Which line (and which method call) throws the NPE? when(bigQueryService.postDatatoBigquery().thenReturn(ArgumentMatchers.anyObject()); doesn't make any sense and wouldn't even compile. You need to call thenReturn after when, not inside it. Also, you cannot return anyObject() because that's a matcher, which must be used as argument to the stubbed call inside when.
